# Why Android Studio does not run App in Android mobiles after gradle update?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

[image: Result of implementation of the program]

When I start running my app, it was loading and running on mobile phone normally.

but after installing android SDK Build-tools 23.0.1 and google USB driver I can't run the app at all.

I mean when I press Run Icon from Android Studio no thing happened or load to my mobile.

Just all process are shown in attached image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've ran the Gradle help task.

You need to run one of the `install` tasks.

[image: Gradle window]